# How to use MapReduce in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Why do we use MapReduce? and what are some use cases?

Comment: For a general example of how MapReduce is used at a high level, why not start with the original MapReduce paper from Google? http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html

Comment: The word count example that Doug answered with, will give you a great insight into what can be accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic example is counting the occurrence of words in a very large collection of documents.  You can use the map step to generate a set of word counts for every document in parallel, then use the reduce step to collate all the words found in each document to a global count.

Here is a link to the documentation page you were probably looking for:
http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html